# Selecting drop down fills text box not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I believe this would be a stupid question. However, i am going nuts to figure out on how to resolve this problem.

I am trying to design a small web app, in which when you select an option from the drop-down, information in the text box fills automatically.

This works perfectly in firefox, however does not work in chrome.

Below is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script>

function myCopy() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myText");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("Copy");
}

function emaila() {
    document.getElementById("myText").value += 'I hope you are going good.\n\n' 
}

function emailb() {
    document.getElementById("myText").value += 'As per our recent conversation, this email is in regards to your Workwear inquiry. Please find the proof of delivery which is attached to this email.\n\n'
}

</script>

<body>

<select class="block2" autocomplete="off">
<option value="">Email Template's</option>
  <option value="1" onClick="emaila()">Greeting</option>
  <option value="3" onClick="emailb()">POD</option>
  <option value="4" onClick="emailc()">Forward to Relevant Team</option>
  <option value="5" onClick="emaile()">Sales Lead</option>
<option value="2" onClick="emaild()">Thank You</option>
</select>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
<textarea id="myText" class="textbox"></textarea>
<div>
<button type="button" class="block11" onClick="document.getElementById('myText').value = ''">Clear</button></div>
<div><button type="button" class="block12" onclick="myCopy()">Copy</button></button></div>

</body>
```

It would be amazing if someone could enlighten me on this?

Comment: you want to copy from the clipboard or the select

Comment: What i want to do is... copy the value from function emaila and auto populate it in the text box, once the user presses on the option greeting from the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the function onchange event of the select. You cant call function on click of options

```js
function myCopy() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myText");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("Copy");
  
}
function func(){
var x=document.querySelector('select').selectedIndex;
if(x==1)
emaila();
if(x==2)
emailb()
}
function emaila() {
  document.getElementById("myText").value += 'I hope you are going good.\n\n'
}

function emailb() {
  document.getElementById("myText").value += 'As per our recent conversation, this email is in regards to your Workwear inquiry. Please find the proof of delivery which is attached to this email.\n\n'
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <select class="block2" autocomplete="off" onchange="func()">
    <option value="">Email Template's</option>
    <option value="1" onClick="emaila()">Greeting</option>
    <option value="3" onClick="emailb()">POD</option>
    <option value="4" onClick="emailc()">Forward to Relevant Team</option>
    <option value="5" onClick="emaile()">Sales Lead</option>
    <option value="2" onClick="emaild()">Thank You</option>
  </select>
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
    <textarea id="myText" class="textbox"></textarea>
    <div>
      <button type="button" class="block11" onClick="document.getElementById('myText').value = ''">Clear</button></div>
    <div><button type="button" class="block12" onclick="myCopy()">Copy</button></div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey mate, i tried using this in the code. However, when i use 2 select drop-downs simultaneously, the first works and the second does not.

Comment: Give both of them Id and select the element using the Id instead of tag name

Comment: Yes i used the logic you mentioned above and it worked.

Comment: If it helped upvote and mark it as correct so it can help others too

Answer (score 0):

You can call onchange event on select and then use conditional statement to set the textarea value

```html
<select class="block2" id="mySelect" onchange="myOption()" autocomplete="off">
<option value="">Email Template's</option>
  <option value="1" >Greeting</option>
  <option value="3">POD</option>
  <option value="4">Forward to Relevant Team</option>
  <option value="5">Sales Lead</option>
<option value="2">Thank You</option>
</select>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
<textarea id="myText" class="textbox"></textarea>
<div>
<button type="button" class="block11" onClick="document.getElementById('myText').value = ''">Clear</button></div>
<div><button type="button" class="block12" onclick="myCopy()">Copy</button></button></div>
<script>
function myCopy() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myText");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("Copy");
}

function myOption() {
var select = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
if (select == '1') {
document.getElementById("myText").value = "I hope you are going good.\n\n";
}
if (select == '3') {
document.getElementById("myText").value = "As per our recent conversation, this email is in regards to your Workwear inquiry. Please find the proof of delivery which is attached to this email.\n\n";
}

}
</script>
```